# Spring Secutiry requires-channel="https" cuando se accede a través de un servidor proxy

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Tengo un proyecto hecho en Spring MVC con Spring Security y tengo una duda acerca de la configuración de https.
Al servidor donde está alojada la aplicación se accede a través de un servidor fachada. El servidor fachada (servidor1) tiene un Apache que hace las redirecciones con ProxyPass y ProxyPassReverse de la siguiente manera:

```
ProxyPass               /app/ http://servidor2:8080/app/
ProxyPassReverse        /app/ http://servidor2:8080/app/

ProxyPass               /app http://servidor2:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse        /app http://servidor2:8080/app
```

Por lo tanto, a la aplicación accedo a través de "http://servidor1/app". Todo funciona bien salvo cuando entro en la página de login.

En la configuración de seguridad del proyecto tengo puesto lo siguiente.

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </port-mappings>
</http>
```

Yo quiero que al escribir en el navegador:

```
http://servidor1/app/login.html
```

Me aparezca:

```
https://servidor1/app/login.html
```

Sin embargo, lo que está apareciendo es:

```
https://servidor2:8443/app/login.html
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme para saber qué necesito añadir a mi configuración? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La configuración para que la url no cambie es propia del Apache, no del servidor en el que tienes tu aplicación.

Es posible que el problema sea que no tienes configurada la directiva [ProxyPreserveHost](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/studio.310/studio_install/src/cidi_studio_reverse_proxy_apache_proxypreservehost.html), que permite que el salto del servidor de front-end al de back-end sea transparente para el usuario.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

[Aquí](https://www.alvaroreig.com/como-configurar-un-proxy-inverso-con-apache/) tienes un ejemplo completo de cómo configurar un proxy con Apache.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con la nueva configuración, el navegador va a la dirección correcta, sin embargo aparece el mensaje "La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente". Cuando activo el Firebug veo que se está recibiendo continuamente la respuesta HTTP 302 Moved Permanently. He probado que cuando quito requires-channel="https" de la configuración de Spring, todo funciona correctamente (pero sin https). Pero lógicamente necesito que se utilice https. Estoy tratando de averiguar a qué puede deberse, cualquier ayuda la agradezco.